# Module, Class and Method wise memory usage in Compact Framework

Tags: c#, .net, profiling, compact-framework2.0

I would like to know whether is it possible to know the memory and cpu usage in currently running compact framework .net application? The purpose of this is that I want to create monitor tool which will display this info on remote machine, so that I will get the updated status of my application.

Please help.

Thanks,
Omky

Answer (score 1):

I believe there was an article on MSDN about this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172525%28v=vs.80%29.aspx